# Need to remove extra string from the URL

Tags: java

I need to remove extra cobra string from the below URL:

URL:
https://cigs-dev.capgroup.com/cobra/cobra/broker/

Result :
https://cigs-dev.capgroup.com/cobra/broker/

Comment: Looks like you did it.

Comment: So why can't you use substring, indexof etc. or replaceFirst?

Comment: Links no longer work, this will unlikely to help anyone in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following code:

```
String url = "https://cigs-dev.capgroup.com/cobra/cobra/broker/";  
String url0 = url.substring(0,30);  
String url1 = url.substring(36,49);  
String newUrl = url0 + url1;  
System.out.println(newUrl);
```